# show forbidden access after set cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies, http-status-code-403, setcookie

I made (asp core) an e commerce website.I used cookies for shopping and compare list.Before adding cookies my website works well, but after I added cookies(add product to cart or compare list) when I want to open compare page or any page it shows this error:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Is there a problem with my code? or is it my host settings?

This is my code:

```
var cookie = compare+ "=" + JSON.stringify(items) + ";path=/";
document.cookie = cookie;
```

Comment: Hi @persian boy, 403 indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. Could you please share more details about how do you set cookie and your Startup.cs ?

Comment: i set (id,title,img address) as cookie because i don't want to get value from server;

Answer (score 0):

Probabily because you had other cookie for authentication.

With this code you probably *overwrite* the authentication cookie.

Try to set some breakpoints and check the code.

Comment: Tnx for answering... When I compile it by visual studio it's work fine. could it be because same path by authentication cookie.? I use identity authentication

Comment: I don't think so, the cookies are stored by name.
Try to remove the "path" and check again.

Comment: What's the value of "compare" ?
Could you please attach the other cookies values?

Comment: i set )id,title,and image address) as cookie.i use this because i don't want to get info from server every time;  change cookie's path (set path=shop)and now the problem is only on cookies specific page.